# Transforming conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Does somebody know why the following equation holds?

$$P(A,B|C) = P(A|B,C) P(B|C)$$

Which rule is used? I think it is not Bayes' rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the rule $P(Y|X) = \frac{P(Y,X)}{P(X)}$:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A,B|C) &= \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)} \\
&= \frac{P(A|B,C)P(B,C)}{P(C)} \\
&= P(A|B,C)\frac{P(B,C)}{P(C)} \\
&= P(A|B,C)P(B|C)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It's because:
$$
P(A|B , C) = \frac{ P(A \cap B \cap C) }{ P(B \cap C) }=\frac{P((A \cap B)|C) \cdot P(C)}{P(B|C) \cdot P(C)}=\frac{\rm{P}((A\cap B)|C)}{\rm{P}(B|C)}
$$